# how to twist a sweep around a spiral in solidworks

Tags: solidworks

[image].

I create two helixes, identical except for two different diameters of wind.  connecting their ends, I create a spiral slide as a surface.  I then create an hour-glass like revolved surface, then use the intersection of these two surfaces to create a helix that starts out with larger diameter, gets smaller, then gets large again.  I then create a sketch at the end of this and use the two sketches to define a spiraling sweep.  the problem is, the sweep doesn't twist properly as it follows the helix.  I would like it to twist such that if a surface of the sweep was tangent to the original hour-glass like revolved surface, it stays that way all the way along.  I think this must be possible, but as you can see in the image, that is not what it's doing.

[image]

Comment: just realized I can do the thing much simpler using the twist part of the flex command.. :-D

Comment: done.. worked like a charm.. :-)